# Pegar resultado de uma expressão em c++

Tags: c++, string, c++11, vector, matemática

Estou quase terminando meu interpretador de expressões. Mas não tenho a menor ideia de como fazer a parte mais importante : O resultado

Eu aprenderia muito com qualquer ideia.

main.cpp

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>

//defines
#define space ' '

//disables any deprecation warning
#pragma warning(disable : 4996)

//usings
using std::vector;
using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

long double nabs(long double dub) {
    return -abs(dub);
}

string remove_char(string str, char c = space) {
    str.erase(std::remove(str.begin(), str.end(), c), str.end());
    return str;
}

long double parse(string str) {
    return std::stold(str);
}

bool try_parse(string str)
{
    char* end = 0;
    double val = strtod(str.c_str(), &end);
    return end != str.c_str() && val != HUGE_VAL;
}

char first_char(string str) {
    return *str.c_str();
}

bool is_opr(string str) {
    return first_char(str) == '&';
}

string &first_item(vector<string> vec) {
    return vec[0];
}

vector<string> get_types(vector<string> vec) {
    for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++) {
        string &s = vec[i];
        bool doubly = try_parse(s);
        bool amp = is_opr(s);

        //if unknown
        if (!doubly && !amp) {
            s = "<unk> " + s;
            continue;
        }
        //if operator
        else if (!doubly && amp) {
            s = "<opr> " + s;
            continue;
        }
        //if number
        else if (doubly && !amp) {
            s = "<dub> " + s;
            continue;
        }

    }
    return vec;
}

/*
  |
  |
  |
  V
*/
long double get_result(vector<string> vec) {
    long double val;
    for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++) {
        //código...
    }
    return val;
}

vector<string> split(string s, const char c = space)
{
    string buff{ "" };
    vector<string> v;

    for (auto n : s)
    {
        if (n != c) buff += n; else
            if (n == c && buff != "") { v.push_back(buff); buff = ""; }
    }
    if (buff != "") v.push_back(buff);

    return v;
}

string simplify(string expr) {
    string iexpr = expr;
    for (int i = 0; i < iexpr.length(); i++) {

        char& c = iexpr[i];

        if (c == '+')
            iexpr.replace(i, 1, " &ad ");
        else if (c == '-')
            iexpr.replace(i, 1, " &sb ");
        else if (c == '*')
            iexpr.replace(i, 1, " &mp ");
        else if (c == '/')
            iexpr.replace(i, 1, " &dv ");

    }
    return iexpr;
}


int main() {

    vector<string> sep_rep = get_types(split(simplify("-21 + 32 - 3 * 2")));
    for (auto str : sep_rep) {
        cout << str << endl;
    }

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Depende. Para pegar o resultado, você vai ter que fazer a análise sintática desse `vector<string>` e então interpretar o resultado. Se você só precisar de algo bobinho que não tem parênteses e nem precedência de operadores, não é muito difícil, mas também não será muito funcional. Se precisar de algo que tenha ou que vá ter depois parênteses e precedência, aí é algo bem trabalhoso e o resultado será um código significativamente maior do que o que você fez para a análise léxica.

Comment: O que você está querendo fazer é a análise sintática. Se você não estiver apenas querendo algo bem simples e bobinho, recomendo ler isso para começar: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181635/132 e depois dar uma lida nisso também: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/180927/132. Vale a pena ver essa outra também: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2044/132

Comment: Pergunta relacionada (não é duplicata): https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/308306/132

Comment: Vou começar pelo bobinho depois penso em ver algo maior.

Comment: Vitor Stafusa, Essa pergunta relacionada é minha

Comment: Eu sei. Eu costumo colocar esse tipo de comentário em perguntas seriais para que outros usuários que esbarrem na sua pergunta não pensem que é duplicata da outra. Ou então os que não entenderem alguma coisa, que vejam sua outra pergunta para entender.

Answer (score 0):

Deu um trabalho fazer isso.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>

//defines
#define space ' '

//disables any deprecation warning
#pragma warning(disable : 4996)

//usings
using std::vector;
using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

long double nabs(long double dub) {
    return -abs(dub);
}

string remove_char(string str, char c = space) {
    str.erase(std::remove(str.begin(), str.end(), c), str.end());
    return str;
}

long double parse(string str) {
    return std::stold(str);
}

bool try_parse(string str) {
    char* end = 0;
    long double val = strtold(str.c_str(), &end);
    return end != str.c_str() && val != HUGE_VALL && val != -HUGE_VALL;
}

char first_char(string str) {
    return *str.c_str();
}

bool is_opr(string str) {
    return first_char(str) == '&';
}

string &first_item(vector<string> vec) {
    return vec[0];
}

vector<string> get_types(vector<string> vec) {
    for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++) {
        string &s = vec[i];
        bool doubly = try_parse(s);
        bool amp = is_opr(s);

        //if unknown
        if (!doubly && !amp) {
            s = "<unk> " + s;
            continue;
        }
        //if operator
        else if (!doubly && amp) {
            s = "<opr> " + s;
            continue;
        }
        //if number
        else if (doubly && !amp) {
            s = "<dub> " + s;
            continue;
        }

    }
    return vec;
}

long double interpretar_numero(string dub) {
    if (dub.substr(0, 6).compare("<dub> ") != 0) {
        throw "Não deu para interpretar como número " + dub;
    }
    return parse(dub.substr(6));
}

long double get_result(vector<string> vec) {
    if (vec.at(0).compare("<opr> &sb") == 0 || vec.at(0).compare("<opr> &ad") == 0) {
        vec.insert(vec.begin(), "<dub> 0");
    }
    long double val = interpretar_numero(vec.at(0));
    for (int i = 1; i < vec.size(); i += 2) {
        std::string op = vec.at(i);
        if (vec.size() == i + 1) throw "Esperava um número antes do fim";
        long double ot = interpretar_numero(vec.at(i + 1));

        if (op.compare("<opr> &ad") == 0) {
            val += ot;
        } else if (op.compare("<opr> &sb") == 0) {
            val -= ot;
        } else if (op.compare("<opr> &mp") == 0) {
            val *= ot;
        } else if (op.compare("<opr> &dv") == 0) {
            val /= ot;
        } else {
            throw "Esperava um operador";
        }
    }
    return val;
}

vector<string> split(string s, const char c = space) {
    string buff{ "" };
    vector<string> v;

    for (auto n : s) {
        if (n != c) {
            buff += n;
        } else if (n == c && buff != "") {
            v.push_back(buff);
            buff = "";
        }
    }
    if (buff != "") v.push_back(buff);

    return v;
}

string simplify(string expr) {
    string iexpr = expr;
    for (int i = 0; i < iexpr.length(); i++) {

        char& c = iexpr[i];

        if (c == '+') {
            iexpr.replace(i, 1, " &ad ");
        } else if (c == '-') {
            iexpr.replace(i, 1, " &sb ");
        } else if (c == '*') {
            iexpr.replace(i, 1, " &mp ");
        } else if (c == '/') {
            iexpr.replace(i, 1, " &dv ");
        }
    }
    return iexpr;
}

int main() {

    vector<string> sep_rep = get_types(split(simplify("-21 + 32 - 3 * 2")));
    for (auto str : sep_rep) {
        cout << str << endl;
    }
    try {
        cout << "R: " << get_result(sep_rep) << endl;
    } catch (const char *e) {
        cout << "Erro: " << e;
    } catch (string e) {
        cout << "Erro: " << e;
    }

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

A função `get_result(vector<string>)` ficou bem complicada, mas o que ela faz é o seguinte:

1. Se houver um sinal de mais ou de menos no começo, coloca um zero antes.
2. Interpreta o primeiro elemento do vetor como um número e põe o valor correspondente em `val`.
3. Interpreta os elementos seguintes do vetor como pares no formato [`op`, `ot`], onde `ot` são os números estão nas posições ímpares e `op` são os operadores nas posições pares.
4. Para cada par [`op`, `ot`], utiliza o operador `op` com os valores `val` e `ot` e guarda o resultado em `val`.
5. Se o vetor não tiver uma quantidade ímpar de strings, ou se o `val` ou o `ot` não puderem ser interpretados como números ou se o `op` não puder ser interpretado como um operador, lança uma string como exceção.

A saída gerada é a seguinte:

```
<opr> &sb
<dub> 21
<opr> &ad
<dub> 32
<opr> &sb
<dub> 3
<opr> &mp
<dub> 2
R: 16
```

O motivo de ser 16 é que ele transforma "*- 21 + 32 - 3 * 2*" em "*0 - 21 + 32 - 3 * 2*". Então ele interpreta o "*0*" como `val`. Faz "*0 - 21*" e chega a *-21* como resposta. Faz "*-21 + 32*" e chega em *11*. Faz "*11 - 3*" e chega em *8*. E por último, faz "*8 * 2*" e chega em *16*.

[**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/LXYDxV)

Comment: Foi útil... Mas preciso saber para que a funcao "compare()" serve

Comment: @MariaCristina http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/

Comment: Me chama de Gabriel, é meu nome,É uma conta temporaria, Vou criar uma conta chamada "project math boost"